# How to add the domain to the Link field?

Tags: entities, uri, 9, social-network

I activated the Link module that is part of Drupal core. I want to add on the user profiles fields with links to social pages and limit the domain used in the link.

How can I add such restriction to the link field?

I also tried the [Social Media Links Block and Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_media_links) module, but it uses a third-party library for the icons and it does not suit me.

I would like to make the link form elements appear like in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

1. Implement [hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter/9.3.x), and add an #element_prefix key in front of the URL field with the domain. This will handle the display.
2. [Create a custom validation constraint](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint) that limits the URL element of the Link field, and add it to the field on the user (using method #2 on the linked page).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a method without a custom code ?

Comment: Not from me. Hopefully someone else may give you an alternative solution.